# Relating conductor current with temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-current

I'm working with heating wires and I want to prove that one only needs to know the current to estimate the temperature, assuming the wire has a constant radius.

Can I just say that if, for a given current $I$ and a length $\Delta l$:

$$  P =  I^{2} \Delta R  \propto T_1  $$

Then for a length $L$

$$ LP = I^{2}R \propto T_2 $$

Where $T_1 = T_2$

Or do I need a more elaborate proof with different equations?

Maybe relating the mass of the objects with power dissipation.

Answer (score 0):

When the temperature change range is small (less than 50 degrees C), power is proportional to the wire temperature. If the temperature change range is a few hundred degrees C, it is non-linear.

Also bear in mind, that resistance change with temperature. So even power is proportional to temperature, current is not. $$I^2 \propto \frac TR = \frac T{\alpha T+R_0} $$